# wpf datagrid cell validation

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid, cell

Somehow my datagrid consider whole column as integer when each cell of that column has numbers. And it wont allow my to update cell with text value. I dont want to have any kind of validation on my grid. How do I disable validation from every cell.

here is image of what I have:

[image]

Comment: If you're just using a standard data grid it should not do any data validation unless you set it up.  Are you binding to a view model or something that might be throwing an exception?

Comment: I am importing excel file into my datagrid. and I used OleDataSource to populate datagrid rows and columns. I just noticed that if column type is double then grid consider that column as a double and not allowing me to enter any kind of string

Comment: How are you binding your grid, are you binding to a view model?  Can you post (at a minimum) some of your XAML and maybe some code for the view model you're using?

Answer (score 0):

declare you clr properties as string.

Comment: can you pls explain me in detail. I am importing excel file into my datagrid. and I used OleDataSource to populate datagrid rows and columns. I just noticed that if column type is double then grid consider that column as a double and not allowing me to enter any kind of string